# Weak relaxation of a strongly lower semi-continuous functional

Tags: banach-spaces, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, duality, semicontinuity

Let $F$ be a lower semicontinuous functional on a Banach space $X$, wrt its strong topology.  Is there a known form for the relaxation (lower semicontinuous envelope) of $F$ with respect to the weak topology on $X$?